# GCE exported disk image to VMDK / VDI to boot as a local VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, google-cloud-platform

I've taken a snapshot of GCE instance then converted it to a standalone disk then finally into an image.

This image is in the Google cloud, so as to make it downloadable I had it pushed to google storage and downloaded it. I now have the .tar.gz file and the .raw file inside it.

Get .tar.gz & .RAW as mentioned here : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image

The raw file as such cannot be used by VM software. So I used qemu to convert it to a vmdk, VHD, VHDX but there was no way I was able to boot it on a VMware VM. How to convert or use this GCE exported .raw file and make it bootable on a local VM ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert .raw file which is downloaded from the image export of GCE to .vdi via VBoxManage command like:

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw /path/to/disk.raw /path/to/disk.vdi --format VDI
```